# Select query : from clause is having multple tables, but i want where clause to have condition on only two tables

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

For eg:

```
SELECT aa.name, aa.id
    FROM ba_acct_memo aa, acct_mast bb
    WHERE (aa.cod_acct_no=bb.cod_acct_no AND aa.flg_mnt_status='U' 
      and bb.flg_mnt_status='A')
```

gives 1 row(for eg)

but

```
SELECT aa.name, aa.id
    FROM ba_acct_memo aa, acct_mast bb, college cc
    WHERE (aa.cod_acct_no=bb.cod_acct_no AND aa.flg_mnt_status='U'
      and bb.flg_mnt_status='A')
```

gives same result as in first query but giving it, as many number of rows which are there in college table.

But it should work just as like first query.

Can someone explain the weird behaviour of my query?

Comment: If you can formulate a rule for *which* row from `college` should be used to complete the query request, we can put that condition into the query.

Comment: you need a join between your tables.

Comment: Hi Damien, As of now I dont want to put any condition on college table. But,What is making this to show the result multiple times by just putting this table in from clause ?

Comment: if there are 2 rows in table A, and 3 rows in table B, the rules of SQL say that `A,B` in a from clause produces 6 rows - with each row in table A matched to each row in table B. That's just a basic rule.

Comment: ok fine for eg, the where condtion on A and B results in 1 row. So that will be multiplied by as many no of rows in Table C for eg 10 ( if i just put in from clause), So wll I get 10 rows ?

Comment: In addition to my above comment,
select a.name
from A a,B b C c
where a.name=b.name , this will give 10 rows ?

Comment: Yes, if table C has ten rows, you'll get 10* however many rows you had before. It's called a Cartesian join, and why I said (in my first comment) that you'd need to give us a rule for *which* of those 10 rows should be selected, if you still only want a single row result.

Answer (score 0):

Following Steps will help you to understand (Inner) Join.

```
            --Create Table 1 :
            Create Table #Table1 
            (
                Roll_No INT ,
                Student_Name Varchar(50)
            )
            Go

            --Create Table 2 :
            Create Table #Table2
            (
                Roll_No INT, 
                Student_Address Varchar(200)
            )
            Go

            --Create Table 3 :
            Create Table #Table3
            (
                Roll_No INT, 
                 Student_Contact_No Varchar(10) 
            )
            Go

            -- Insert Values into #Table1: 
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('1','John')
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('2','Alex')
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('3','Mike')
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('4','Steve')
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('5','Jack')
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('6','Vicky')
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('7','Sid')
            Insert into #Table1 Values ('8','Tom')

            -- Insert Values into #Table2: 
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('1','1st Street')
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('2','2rd Street')
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('3','3rd Street')
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('4','4th Street')
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('5','5th Street')
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('6','6th Street')
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('7','7th Street')
            Insert into #Table2 Values ('8','8th Street')

            -- Insert Values into #Table3: 
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('1','123-123')
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('2','123-111')
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('3','123-122')
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('4','123-125')
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('5','123-126')
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('6','123-116')
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('7','123-145')
            Insert into #Table3 Values ('8','123-132')

            --View Data :
            Select * from #Table1

            Select * from #Table2

            Select * from #Table3

            -- First Query :  (With Out Third Table) : 

            Select A.Roll_No,A.Student_Name,B.Student_Address from #Table1 A, #Table2 B 
            Where a.Roll_No = B.Roll_No
            and a.Roll_No = 1

            --It will Retrun One Record. If you add third table in this query with out  join with any other tables ( Table 1 and Table 2 )

            -- Secord Query :

            Select A.Roll_No,A.Student_Name,B.Student_Address from #Table1 A, #Table2 B , #Table3 C
            Where a.Roll_No = B.Roll_No
            and a.Roll_No = 1

            --It will return 8 Same Records. (Because Table 3 having 8 Records) 
            --You can understand when execute why it is return 8 records.

            -- Third Query : 
            Select *  from #Table1 A, #Table2 B , #Table3 C
            Where a.Roll_No = B.Roll_No
            and a.Roll_No = 1

            --Delete some records from #Table 3 :
            Delete #Table3 Where Roll_No > 5

            --Execute again Third Query :

            -- Third Query : 
            Select *  from #Table1 A, #Table2 B , #Table3 C
            Where a.Roll_No = B.Roll_No
            and a.Roll_No = 1

            --Clean Up:
            Drop table #Table1
            Drop table #Table2
            Drop table #Table3
```